# how to count a user coupon in sql - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm newbie in MySQL

I want to count a user coupon token that used by other people to use in app

I currently use a php loop to calculate how many people use a user token

Is there any way to do this in one query that return all users and its used coupon number? I want something like this `SELECT user.id , Count(payment.id) from ..`

**please pay attention I don't use `user.id = ?`**

I loop this function to achieve every user coupon used number that is too slow

```
   public function countInvitationByUserID($id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT * FROM payment, coupon, users
            WHERE payment.payment_coupon_id = coupon.id
            AND coupon.coupon_token = users.user_coupon_token
            AND users.id = ?
            AND payment.payment_status = 1", array($id)
        );
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

anyone could help to write all of this in one query?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give detail about the schema

Comment: @ManojMohan every user have a coupon that others can register in app via that coupon(is 5 digit number). I want calculate score for every user by users coupon that other people registered with that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SELECT user_id, count(coupon.id) FROM payment, coupon, users
            WHERE payment.payment_coupon_id = coupon.id
            AND coupon.coupon_token = users.user_coupon_token
            AND payment.payment_status = 1 group by user_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    US.user_id, COUNT(CO.id)
FROM
    payment PT
    INNER JOIN coupon CO ON PT.payment_coupon_id=CO.id
    INNER JOIN users US ON US.user_coupon_token=CO.coupon_token

WHERE
    PT.payment_status = 1
GROUP BY US.user_id;
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help you.